# ¿Como cambiar el plan de energia de mi pc con c#?

Tags: c#

Últimamente mi computadora se sobre calienta solo cuando uso programas pesados por lo que mi solución fue crear un plan de energía en el que cambia algunas cosas de mi pc para que no se sobresaliente, pero yo solo quiero que este plan de energía este activo cuando abro ciertos programas por lo que mi pregunta es:
**¿Existe alguna forma en la que desde un script de c# pueda cambiar entre el plan de energia predeterminado y el que fue creado por mi?**

Answer (score 0):

Con el comando `powercfg -aliases` sacas una lista de todos los planes de energía del sistema. Si mal no voy, `powercfg -L` te muestra el plan de energía actual.

Cada plan de energía tiene un `GUID` asociado con el que puedes acceder y automatizar.
Las librerías de Microsoft relacionadas con las políticas de energía del sistema pueden ayudarte.

- [*Power Policy Classes*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//dd904518(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [*Power Scheme Management*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/managing-power-schemes?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Espero que sirva.